# TimerTask com intervalos longos

Tags: java, android, timer

Eu pretendo desenvolver uma app que ao definir uma determinada hora, agendo uma tarefa com o timertask para ser executada 50 minutos depois e logo após esses 50minutos, repetir por periódos de 50 minutos sucessivamente. Mas acontece que depois de passados 50 minutos da hora agendada, a tarefa não é executada. Mas acontece que testado com tempos mais curtos como 5 minutos, a tarefa executa. Será que o timertask não aceita tempos longos? Aqui vai um exemplo do que poderá ser o meu código:

```
public void startTimer() {
        //set a new Timer
        timer = new Timer();



        //initialize the TimerTask's job
        initializeTimerTask();

        timer.schedule(timerTask, 300000, 300000); 
    }


    public void initializeTimerTask() {

        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                //use a handler to run a toast that shows the current timestamp
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        showNotification();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Para esse tipo de intervalo, é recomendado usar o `AlarmManager` registrando um Intent. Acho que aqui no SO tem varias perguntas e respostas sobre o assunto.

Comment: @Wakim por acaso já usei o AlarmManager para este caso e de alguma forma o resultado era "maluco". Havia momentos em que respeitava o intervalo pretendido mas outras vezes não ... Se calhar estava a usar mal, mas não acredito ...

Comment: Só vejo esse problema se o dispositivo for desligado, ai você precisa registrar novamente. Não sei se você acabou chamando o `setInexactRepeating` ou `set`, mas na versão 19, ele não é executado na hora exata, mas em algum momento após. Isso é feito para economizar bateria. Vale a pena dar uma olhada na documentação: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html. Se você precisar de uma janela exata de tempo, pode usar o `setWindow` (19+): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setWindow(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent).

Comment: @Wakim, vou dar olhada na documentação e experimentar o setWindow ... Obrigado pela ajuda.